# jQuery form submit is refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone please tell me why this code is not working? It's just refreshing the page.

```
 jQuery(document).on('submit', '.comment-form', function (event) {
        alert('hello')
        event.preventDefault();

        const form = jQuery(this);
        const id = form.attr('id');

        console.log(id)


        //do stuff ...


        return false;
    });
```

I have two of these forms on the same page. They are added dynamically using Handlebars.

```
<form class="column-form comment-form" id="{{_id}}">
    <div class="">
        <div class="col-12-10 col-medium-12-12 comment-content">
            <input placeholder="Add a comment" type="text" value="" id="comment-{{_id}}" name="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12-2 col-medium-12-12 flex comment-submit">
            <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

*** Edit ***

```
    jQuery(document).on('submit', '.comment-form', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hello')
    });
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a data validation issue?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I just want it to alert hello. Just to see that it hits that event listener, and it doesn't ... been trying everything.

Comment: Sorry.  There was a // do stuff part, so I thought perhaps the form actually submitted something...

Comment: Are you duplicating IDs in the page?

Comment: "is not working" - do you see `alert('hello')`?

Comment: Are you registering this handler after the DOM has completed loading?

Comment: I don't think so. But why would that matter? I'm listening on `.comment-form` submit and then using the form's id. I would just be posting with the wrong id.

Comment: @Igor no alert ...

Comment: @Amy My code is in a `document.ready` function

Comment: @Ciprian it does not have to be, as long as it is after jQuery library script tag

Comment: weird ... i commented everything inside and left only what's in my edit .. . (i hate that you can't format code properly in SO comments)  and I get the alert. Seems that there is something else breaking it. I will check. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: @Ciprian look for errors in the browser console during page loading

Comment: I just tried that code, and it is working just fine, and does not refresh the page...unless you forgot to link to the jQuery library, or left out a code fragment that override the one you've showed us.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error with my code, don't worry - it's an easy fix.

Have your tried to add:

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

Your code should look like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" class="column-form comment-form" id="{{_id}}">
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-12-10 col-medium-12-12 comment-content">
      <input placeholder="Add a comment" type="text" value="" id="comment-{{_id}}" name="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12-2 col-medium-12-12 flex comment-submit">
      <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `onsubmit="return false;"` is different from the `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` uses now how?

Answer (score -1):

Judging by the fact that you do not see the alert, there is a syntax error in the missing code, which makes the parser throw away the whole script block.

```js
jQuery(document).on('submit', '.comment-form', function(event) {
  alert('hello')
  event.preventDefault();

  const form = jQuery(this);
  const id = form.attr('id');

  console.log(id)


  //do stuff ...


  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="column-form comment-form" id="{{_id}}">
  <div class="">
    <div class="col-12-10 col-medium-12-12 comment-content">
      <input placeholder="Add a comment" type="text" value="" id="comment-{{_id}}" name="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12-2 col-medium-12-12 flex comment-submit">
      <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Uh, what is different between your answer and the OP's question?

Comment: I see no difference

Comment: there is no difference, it demostrates that simple case here works, so that gives OP confidence about the presented code and opportunity to look for errors somewhere else

Comment: The environment

Comment: Why tell people to look for the differences in the first line of your answer if there aren't any?  It's like a Where's Waldo puzzle that doesn't contain a Waldo.